# ggplot gives strange coding for all labels, even when using simple online example?

Tags: r

My plot:

[image], I tried reinstalling R and ggplot twice. I just used the code here:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg)) + geom_point() 
out_path <- "/example.png"   
ggsave(out_path, p, width=8, height=5, dpi=300)
```

This code was just copied from an online example:

http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-scatter-plots-quick-start-guide-r-software-and-data-visualization

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow!  Are you using RStudio or some other interface to R?  Does it render correctly if you just do the `ggplot()` without the `ggsave()`?

Comment: I am working on a linux server. Starting an R interactive session via entering `$R` at the command line. I just installed rstuio and found it gives the same results when using 'ggplot()` instead of `ggsave()`